# Can I write this if statement with a variable declaration on one line?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I was wondering if there was a way to put this on one line?

```
if (auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word)) r->doSomething; // This works fine

if (!auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word)) r->doSomething; // Says "expected an expression"

if (auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word) == false) r->doSomething; // Also doesn't work.
```

I also tried surrounding it with extra brackets, but that doesn't seem to work. I find this really convenient doing it on one line.

Comment: As a side note, I would discourage trying to one line that. In fact, I don't even encourage you to use the return value of an assignment in your conditional, [various compilers actually treat that as a compiler warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hw7c1he.aspx) as it leads easily to bugs. Let alone adding a third step in that task. Make sure your code is readable first and foremost, terse isn't always better.

Comment: I fail to see the point.  If `r` tests as `false`, then evaluating `r->doSomething` will give undefined behaviour, unless a very specific set of conditions are met   (such as `r` being of some class type, that class type providing an `operator!()` or being comparable with `bool`, AND providing an `operator->()` that does not somehow yield a null pointer if the object tests as being `false`)

Comment: @CoryKramer That is not assignment it is initialization and no compilers will give a warning for this. You must be confuding it with the warning compilers give for assignment when the variable is declared before the `if` construct. In that case it serves to protect your from using assignment rather than equivalence. But this is different and can't be confused.

Comment: Having upvoted the comment that compilers won't warn, I still think this sort of excessive terseness is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @MartinBonner I agree somewhat halfheartedly. IMO the only badness involved is the relative inexperience C++ programmers have with this syntax. Go went out of its way to make sure this is _the_ idiomatic way of writing, and I don't think it is in any way excessively terse

Comment: @PasserBy : The problem with `if (auto a = ...)` is that you are doing multiple things in the same line.  Firstly you are initializing `a`, secondly, you are testing the result of that initialization.  In general, I prefer to only do *one* think on one line.

Comment: @MartinBonner In my very little experience, the condition directly depends on the init-statement, and is often trivial, as in this case. Although lumping things together isn't in general a good idea, in this context, I find it perfectly fine

Comment: `auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word) == false` mean `auto r = (getGlobalObjectByName(word) == false)`

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you may wish to consider a null object so that the `getGlobalObjectByName()` call could always succeed, but `doSomething()` has a noop implementation in the null object.  Then you don't have to test `r`, you could just `getGlobalObjectByName(word)->doSomething();`

Comment: I'm surprised the first one works.

Comment: @HotLicks The first construct also works for `for` statements, so why not for `if`s?

Answer (score 52):

Since C++17 you can use an [initializer if-statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

```
if (auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word); !r) r->doSomething;
```

The semantics are:

```
if (init-statement; condition) statement
```

The only difference from the "traditional" if-statement is the `init-statement`, which initializes a variable in the block scope, similar to for-loops.

Comment: I keep on cursing the language for adding more features, but some things I dig. Thanks

Comment: @Zindarod The expression after the semicolon behaves just like it was before.

Comment: @Zindarod Counter question: Why do you assume that `r` is a pointer?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Because `r->` is used.

Comment: It might be a non-pointer type with an overloaded `->` operator.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, it might very well be. Althoug its a bit of a stretch in this case :)

Comment: But assuming otherwise is also unnecessary.

Comment: Is there any reason `if (auto r = !getGlobalObjectByName(word)) r->doSomething;` wouldn't work?

Comment: If one doesn't have C++17, would the comma operator work?

Comment: @Justsalt No, because the comma operator breaks up expressions, not statements. A comma here would just be interpreted as a separator between variables being defined (leading to a parse error), not as the comma operator.

Comment: I can see a compiler doing `if (a = 3, a<b)` and assigning the result of `a<b` to a without warning.

Comment: You should give the name of the language and link to the appropriate cppreference page, so new people can get a better overview of the feature.

Comment: @tambre I linked the cppreference page. What do you mean by the name of the language

Comment: @PasserBy Apologies, I missed a word. I meant the name of the given language feature, which in this case is "initializer if-statement". I'll submit an edit myself, if that's OK.

Answer (score 13):

If you have C++17, use the `if (init statement; condition)` form.  If not, you have three choices:

- Stop trying to keep this all on one line.  For example:

  ```
  auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word);
  if (!r) r->doSomething();
  ```
- Use an `else`:

  ```
  if (auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word)) {} else r->doSomething();
  ```

(Note that this requires that `r` is a smart pointer with *very* strange semantics for the `operator bool()` function.  OTOH, I assume this is actual a short piece of example code, rather than your actual code).

I think I would only use the `else` form if it was *really* important to keep everything on one line (to preserve a tabular formatting of the code for example).

Comment: `r` may be something other than a smart pointer, e.g. a `Status` class, which converts to `false` to indicate failure and can e.g. provide an error message in this case.

Comment: @Ruslan  Yes, it could, but overloading `operator ->` to provide error messages seems like operator overloading abuse to me.  `r.Error().doSomething()` would be cleaner.

Comment: Well yes indeed, didn't think of the `operator->`.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is fine. By defining the variable inside the *if* you restrict its *scope*. That helps to reduce the number of stray variables after they have served their purpose.

Using this technique, if you want to follow the *negative* path, you need to use **else** like this:

```
if(auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word))
{
    r->doSomething();
}
else
{
    // r == nullptr
    // so do something else
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also a way to do this with lambdas and C++14 but it does seem rather silly.

```
[](auto r){ if(!r)r->doSomething(); }(getGlobalObjectByName(word));
```

In C++11 you could also do this horrible mess (same idea, just no `auto`)

```
[](decltype(getGlobalObjectByName(word)) r){ if(!r)r->doSomething(); }(getGlobalObjectByName(word));
```

It is certainly no better than this clearer C++11 version mentioned by [Martin Bonner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46001418/2043622):

```
{
    auto r = getGlobalObjectByName(word);
    if(!r)r->doSomething();
}
```

Here your code is clear that you want `r` to only be around for the duration of the if statement.

Comment: I don't understand what's happening in the first line you wrote. You declare a lambda and then instantly call a function after it on the one line, as if the return value of the function is passed as the argument to the lambda.  Is this a feature of C++14? What's it called?

Comment: @Zebrafish the C++14 feature is auto parameters for lambdas. The code is simply constructing a lambda and immediately calling its operator(). If I used a type instead of auto I could do it in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Before C++17 you can define a wrapper class, like here:

```
#include <utility>
template<typename T>
class NotT
{
    T t;
public:
    template<typename U>
    NotT(U&& u) : t(std::move(u)) {}
    explicit operator bool() const { return !t; }
    T      & value()       { return t; }
    T const& value() const { return t; }
};
template<typename T> NotT<T> Not(T&& t)
{
    return NotT<T>(std::move(t));
}

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if(auto p=Not(std::make_shared<int>(2134)))
        std::cout << "!p: p=" << p.value().get() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "!!p: p=" << p.value().get() << ", *p=" << *p.value() << '\n';

}
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b62fff7543695af3)