# declaring a variable in if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

Please condiser the following snippet

```
//foo is just a random function which returns error code
if(int err = foo() == 0){
    //err should contain the error code
    ...
}
```

The problem with that is `err` contains the result of `foo() == 0`, and what I want to evalute is `int err = foo();` then `if(err == 0)` but inside the `if` statement.

I have already tried `if((int err = foo()) == 0)` and it doesn't work. 
Also, I don't want to do `int err; if((err = foo) != 0))`.

Is this possible ?

Comment: No. -----------

Comment: Actually may be in c++17?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68967429/how-to-define-variable-and-compare-value-inside-if-statement (bad dupe target?)

Comment: Not like this, but something similar works. `if (int err = foo())` is a boolean expression, which checks for 'Not 0', meaning you'll need to put your 'on Error' code into the else.

Comment: If you have C++20, you can write `if(int err=foo(); err==0) {}` (or indeed 17 it seems).

Comment: You can but it doesn't always mean you should. Declaring it above the if statement improves readability. Your future self will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ 17 and onwards you can use [if statements with initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

```cpp
if (int err = foo(); err == 0) {
   ...
}
```